# Cannot figure out why my SQL query is not returning a result

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the entire code guys. I am trying to create a simple user authentication system.
Here is the entire code guys. I am trying to create a simple user authentication system.
Here is the entire code guys. I am trying to create a simple user authentication system.
Here is the entire code guys. I am trying to create a simple user authentication system.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['username']) OR !isset($_POST['password']) OR empty($_POST['username']) OR empty($_POST['password'])) {

echo "Please login:";

echo '<form method="POST">';

echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username">';
echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password"></br>';

echo '<input type="submit" value="Login">';

echo '</form>';

  }

    else {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

try {

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userauth', 'norman101', 'beecher123');

}

catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo 'ERROR:' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username=?, AND password=?";

$pds = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$pds->execute(array($username, $password));

$row = $pds->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($row);

}

?>
```

Comment: Assuming that there should only be one row in the table for each user, you should not need to specify the password in the query. 

NOTE.  it is considered very bad practice to store passwords in the database, you should store only a non-reversible hash of the password, so that client code can perform the same hash algorithm on password attempts from clients, and compare the hash with what is stored in the DB.  Non-reversible means the actual password cannot be reproduced from the hash, and is therefore never stored in your system.

Comment: I am not storing the password in the database. I have hashed it with md5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$pds= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo  WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
$pds->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
$row = $pds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I have to aquire the username and password because this is the framework for a userauth system I am building. I have to match the username and hashed password.

Comment: So what you are passing in `?`

Comment: the ? is standard syntax for PDO

Comment: Thank you Yogus. I will have to look into PDO syntax more. Hard trying to find literature. Not only did you answer the question but you gave me very nice insight into how the : syntax works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the AND operator:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username=? AND password=?";
```

Comment: perhaps the password is not a match, run it with just the username and see what happens